# How can Obito combine 4 different nature transformations?

Tags: naruto

How can Obito combine 4 different nature transformations, if he barely managed to control the Juubi inside him?
Using advanced techniques and nature transformations needs some focus on chakra manipulation, so how is he able to do this?

[image: Naruto chapter 639 page 10]
<sup>Obito using the 4 different nature transformations</sup>

[image: Naruto chapter 640 page 8]
<sup>Obito barely managing to control the Juubi</sup>

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/304/is-it-possible-to-combine-all-five-chakra-elements

Comment: My current theory is that it's not actually combining 4 elements (and that the Third is wrong), but is actually Yin element. The chakra rod looks suspiciously like Pain's rods, only they function differently (destroy, rather than pierce and control). Regardless, it's a good question. +1

Answer (score 2):

Obito is the Jinchuuriki of the 10 tails. Having the blood of the Uchiha + having the Rinnegan and the Mangekyo Sharingan + being trained by Madara himself, Obito would have surpassed any living ninja in technique and chakra depth, as well as natural talent. It was even said at one time that he was the same as the "Sage of the 6 paths".

Comment: It was even said at one time that he was the same as the "Sage of the 6 paths". -any proof of this?

Comment: http://ex1.unixmanga.net/onlinereading/?image=Naruto/Naruto%20c638/naruto-4283457.jpg&server=nas.html

Comment: Well, it was said that he was the same as the Sage of Six Paths by Madara, after he became the ten tails' Jinchuuriki. I wouldn't say that Obito surpassed any living ninja in chakra depth (what is that even?) or natural talent. However, having the Juubi and the Rinnegan should be enough to give the user all 5 elements, combining them? That's probably one of the Juubi's abilities? Or it may be that the technique is not an element fusion, but rather Yin or Yinyang element. Read my comment on the question.

Comment: I'm referring to depth in the way Itachi Uchiha described his own chakra a while back. Also, regarding your comment on the question, I wonder why 2 elements wouldn't be good enough for Yin Element and 2 more for Yang Element. A full ying-yang would round out 4 elements, just like the spirit element rounds out earth, air, water, and fire on a pentagram.

Comment: @Elemecca: Yin and Yang are different elements from the Elemental five. They aren't related to the elemental cycle and they are unique on their own. That much was already explained.

Comment: can this be related to the abilites gained from the tailed beast. For eg, naruto can heal people by using the nine tailed fox's chakra. By drawing an analogy we can say that Obito's ability to combine 4 chakra elements comes from becoming the jinchuriki of the 10 tailed beast. Even naruto did not have complete control over the nine tailed beast when his chakra caused wood element to gain life.

Answer (score 0):

See chapter 375 of the manga, page 11. Jiraiya states one who posesses the Rinnegan can use all 6 chakra natures. In addition, controlling the Ten-tails is no mean feat, considering it's likely to be at least ten times as difficult to control as a normal Tailed Beast, which itself is hardly something a skilled shinobi wouldn't think twice about. Also, I'm guessing that controlling the Tailed Beasts doesn't require chakra manipulation and control, but rather willpower and determination - as demonstrated by Naruto himself.