# Kakuzu's way of getting all the five chakra elements

Tags: naruto

So I went back and started reading, or just looking at, really old questions about Naruto, including Shippuden. I read [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/304/is-it-possible-to-combine-all-five-chakra-elements) question, but [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/311/20270) answer got my attention. After looking at the answer, I started to wonder how exactly Kakuzu's methods of getting the chakra natures work.

We know that he gets all the chakra natures by stealing people's hearts throughout the years but once the hearts he has on are damaged or just get too old he has to get new ones. But how does that work? I always thought the nature of the chakra was in the body not exactly the heart. Or do both, body and heart, have the chakra nature, so when Kakuzu gets the hearts he gets part of the chakra nature?

Also, since we also know that Kakuzu has been living for a while, until Kakashi killed him, exactly how old is he? I know he has been living since the First Hokage was alive, which I guess was about 100 years ago, so I think he was at least a little more than 100 years old.

Comment: Kakuzu is 91 y/o when he is killed. I guess it`s similar with how Sasori using chakra in his heart to move his puppets, but Kakuzu using his own body to convert normal chakra into their elemental form.

Answer (score 1):

**This is just the theory**, but I always assumed that since the blood vessels and the chakra network are intricately related, if you take one the other also follows.

Thus when Kakuzu takes the heart of the shinobi he also takes the chakra vessels tied in and around the heart. Thus he would push his own chakra into the heart while his unique body mimics the nature of the chakra vessels of the original body.

Thus he builds his own chakra, uses the handsigns to concentrate/accumulate it, but when nature transforming the chakra he passes it through the heart which acts like a processor to change the chakra nature to the type needed.